# ASP.NET Code Generator

Tags: asp.net, code-generation

I have a SQL Server Database. I would really like to quickly generate a middle-tier and a front-end from this database. I would prefer something that generates web forms if possible. I understand that no code-generator will be phenomenal. However, I just want something to get me up and running quickly that I can then customize as needed.

Can anybody recommend any code-generators?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully used [Code Smith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) (commercial product).
It is a popular templating engine and you will find many templates on the Internet for all kinds of architecture / data access frameworks.

I have also used plain [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) that you can use within Visual Studio without having to install anything (although I would recommend using something like [Tangible T4 Editor](http://www.olegsych.com/2009/04/t4-editor-by-tangible-engineering/) to get color syntax).

Comment: Can you generate UI form with codesmith? If so, can you provide an example

Answer (score 3):

There is [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata). If you can live with MVC, EF4 and MVC3 would be my choice above Dynamic Data.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who is releasing a code generator very soon.  You provide xslts based on the data model to create classes at any layer you want.  Here is the site: [Code Generator](http://thecodegenerator.com/)
Be sure to check out the [sample project](http://thecodegenerator.com/Sample-CS/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio (2005 or greater) you might consider T4 templates. There's a good introductory video at [DNRTV](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=183). T4 is a little known code generation facility that comes with all editions of Visual Studio (even Express I believe).

On some of my projects I have used [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx), a free and open source code generator. This is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Entity Framework to generate objects from database schema, and then use the MVC Framework to generate stronly-typed views that use the said generated objects as models.

Here's a good post on that - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd give [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com) a try, especially the ActiveRecord version. It basically will generate an interface(with Linq) to an existing SQL Server database, For taking it to forms, I suspect you won't find a very good solution because there are so many implementation details that are commonly placed in webforms, such as XSS prevention, how things should look and behave, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a tool that I have use for really rapid application development, is the **asp.net maker**. http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/

I have used it for low budget projects, or where I need for a dirty quick solution, until the final gets ready. What I have did is that I create solution for the easy tables, and make code for the one that need too many thinks to be fix.

**The pros** is that have many future, **its very easy and you do not need to know almost anything to make the interface**, create from the database, all the environment that can edit it, have the opportunity to make a lot of adjustments, and what you get is a better page than the Scaffold can product.

**The negative** is that you stick with what this tool product, and you can not update the pages by your self to make some small changes, because is too complicates one, second if anything change, the pages changes, and even if you rename it and not overwrite it, it maybe not working.

You need to test it and see by your self.

Answer (score 0):

Redbrook Technology has a great ASP.NET forms and code generator. It's also very cheap. Give it a try - [ASP.NET Generator](http://www.redbrooktech.com/codespark.html)